# Calling list objects inside of a list

Tags: python-2.7, list

```
alphabet = ['a','b','c']
numbers = [3,2,1]

print alphabet(numbers)
```

How do I use a list inside of another list? I am trying to get the output "cba" but am running into the following error

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Should the numbers be `2,1,0`? You want to get the letters in `alphabet` at the indices in `numbers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to index the second list, so you're referencing individual integers rather than the list.

For example, `print alphabet[numbers[1]]` is the equivalent of `print alphabet[2]`.

Remember that lists are indexed starting at 0, so for `alphabet = ['a','b','c']`, 'a' is at index 0, 'b' is at index 1, and so on.

To do what you want, you are going to need to use a loop to iterate through the `numbers` list. Something like:

```
alphabet = ['a','b','c']
numbers = [2,1,0]
for n in numbers:
    print alphabet[n]
```